# What is “kioma” used for besides asking for the time?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, correlatives

As I have been taught by the Duolingo course, the word *kioma* is used when asking for the time:

> Kioma horo estas?

I realise that it is made from the word *kiom* + *-a* (to make it an adjective?) but the other correlatives do not seem to have such forms (e.g. there is no *tioa*, *kiea*, etc.).

Is *kioma* an exception that is used only when asking for the current time or does it have a more broad meaning? Can you give any other examples of its use?

Comment: "Taught" and "realize" appear to be spelled wrong. The system does not allow me to suggest this as an edit because fixing these doesn't generate a big enough change to the text to warrant an edit.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Fixed "taught". As for "realise", that is valid British spelling, from what I (double-)checked (I am not a native English speaker).

Comment: Yes, “realise” is good old British spelling. Also, @TomasoAlexander has spelt “spelt” wrong :p

Answer (score 11):

Just think of *kiom* as a numeral like *unu, du, tri...kiom?* (one, two, three...how many?)

*Unua* means *first*, *dua* is *second*, *tria* is *third*, *dudeka* is *twentieth*. *Kioma* is, well, there is no word for it in English (other languages do have such words), but you might imagine something like "how manyeth?". Saying *kioma* you are asking for an ordinal number:

- *Kioma prezidanto de Usono estas Barack Obama? Li estas la kvardek kvara (aŭ: kvardek-kvara).*
- *Kioman lokon vi havas en la atendovico? Mi estas jam la tria, do ne plu daŭros longe.*

In Esperanto we usually tell the time using ordinal numbers: *Estas la kvara (horo). Mi revenos je la naŭa, je la dudeka (horo)*

That's why it is natural to ask *Kioma horo estas?*, but *kioma* is a useful word for many questions.

Comment: oh that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 10):

*Kioma* is used to ask about anything which is an ordered sequence.

Here are some examples of it being used other than to ask the time.

- Kaj li rememoris (kioman fojon en ĉi tiu jaro!) la maljustaĵojn
- De la kioma etaĝo vi estas?
- ĝis kioma grado (dua, tria, ktp.)
- de kioma tago kaj de kiu monato

*Kiome* is much less common. My take is that it's a synonym for *kiom*.

- Kaj ne forgesu, kiome diferencas ankaŭ la popolo ĉi tie kaj tiu de la Atena agora.

The *Ekzercaro* contains examples of correlatives turned into words in this way. Some of these are used moderately often.

- Ekster tio el la diritaj vortoj ni povas ankoraŭ fari aliajn vortojn, per helpo de gramatikaj finiĝoj kaj aliaj vortoj (sufiksoj); ekzemple: tiama, ĉiama, kioma, tiea, ĉi-tiea, tieulo, tiamulo k. t. p. (= kaj tiel plu).

*Kialo* is not on the list, but it springs to mind as an example of a very common word formed from a correlative. *Tiele* is also very commmon (especially in the phrase *tiele diras la Eternulo*. I first encountered it used the way Latin *sic* is used to show a typo or error in a quotation. It often seems like a synonym for *tiel*. According to PIV, it has a stricter meaning: *laŭ tia maniero*.

- kredu al mi, tiele estas pli bone!

In summary, I would say *kioma horo* is hardly an exception. There are lots of words built from correlatives - the list could go on and we haven't even gotten to *kiomope* and the like.