# How to make an adjective of "tie"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The title says it all. I would like to make an adjective relating to a place I am referring to via *tie*, much like I can create *tiama* from *tiam* in the fourth dimension. It does not need to be related to the word *tie* structurally.

A context where such word would be useful is, for example, when speaking of a place (country, subcontinent, area), to mention its culture or habits. The closest I can think of in English is "local" but Russian has a word which fits just perfectly: [тамошний](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (там = there). That being one of the source languages of Esperanto, and actually [using](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9#Russian) *Esperanta* way of creating an adjective from base words, gives me hope there's something more specific than *loka*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adjectives are formed by adding an *-a* to the end. Correlatives are considered whole words (and not roots+ending), so no letters would be removed from *tie*. The result would be *tiea* - and it means just what you suggested.

- La tieaj esperantistoj - the Esperantists who are there.

See also: [What is “kioma” used for besides asking for the time?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/what-is-kioma-used-for-besides-asking-for-the-time/1229#1229)

Comment: Thank you! When the other two answers came I wondered how I could be so stupid to not plainly try gluing an *-a*. But then I realized what has prevented me was that *tie* looked as it already had a suffix, so my mind wanted to either chop something off first, or perhaps add a linking letter. Your sentence "Correlatives are considered whole words, so no letters would be removed [...]" helps greatly, here as well as in other potential questions, I'm sure.

Answer (score 6):

*tiea* appears in [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#tiea):

> ***tiea, ĉi-tiea**. Ekzistanta en tiu, en ĉi tiu loko: *la tieaj produktoj; la ĉi-tiea publiko estas severa.*

There are many of examples of its usage in Tekstaro:

> Ĉiuj personoj, kiuj partoprenis en la **tiea** kongreso, konservis pri ĝi la plej agrablan kaj plej entuziasman memoron por la tuta vivo

(That one being a quote from Zamenhof)

> Kiel urbestro de la **ĉi-tiea** urbo mi havas la devon zorgi pri tio, ke al la traveturantoj kaj al ĉiuj noblaj homoj estu nenia premado.
>
> Ili treege ŝatas la **tiean** bonegan vivon.

Answer (score 2):

### Tiea

[Vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/#tiea):

> **tiea**, **ĉi-tiea**: Ekzistanta en tiu, en ĉi tiu loko: *la tieaj produktoj*; *la ĉi-tiea publiko estas severa*.

[ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/):

> **tiea**: Tiuloka, tie situanta: *mi … restis en la universitata urbo por … fari publikan esperanto-kurson al tieaj loĝantoj*.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this - `La rusian**aj** programistoj estas lertaj.`

If you want to use the word *tie* then you can say *tiea* or *tiuloka* - `La tieaj programistoj estas lertaj.`

> Tiea = Tiuloka, tie situanta (from ReVo)